# What does the word "omnipreneur" mean?

Tags: meaning, nouns

I came across the term "Culinary Omnipreneur" in this week's Times Magazine.

I couldn't find the meaning of the word *omnipreneur* on WordWeb or by googling.

Comment: Can you give the exact sentence in which it was used? And you have it spelled two different ways in your title and question. I suspect it should be *omnipreneur*...a combination of the prefix omni-, meaning "everywhere," and the word entrepreneur.

Comment: No need to down vote.

Comment: Please dont down vote !! If you want to find this word, just buy This week's Time's Magazine - 100 most influential people

Comment: @Mahnax but you didn't yet yours.  Or you didn't see the illogicality.  :-)

Comment: @JLG searching the Time magazine site, it [looks like](http://search.time.com/results.html?N=0&Nty=1&p=0&cmd=tags&srchCat=Full+Archive&Ntt=omnipreneur&x=0&y=0) *Culinary omnipreneur* is a tag line to an article that doesn't appear in a full sentence, so it may be impossible for the OP to give a sentence for context

Comment: aah, you got it !!

Comment: @Medex: please stop ending every sentence in a " !!". That is disturbing on more levels than I can handle. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fashionable to prefix any and every word with an '*omni*'. Today, the prefix *omni* is omnipresent.

*Omnipreneur* is formed from *omni* + *entrepreneur*, one who dabbles in all sorts of businesses, so to speak.

You can look up the prefix *omni-* and the word *entrepreneur* separately for meanings.

Comment: I wonder, though, is the person who was called a *culinary* omnipreneur only dabbling in or interested in things that are culinary...not exactly *omni*, then.

Comment: @JLG the article in question is about a guy who, in addition to being a chef, volunteers by cooking food for people, owns several restaurants, and gives lectures on food science at Harvard. So, he has a hand in anything having to do with the culinary arts.

Answer (score 8):

Merriam-Webster's section on new words and slang has an [entry](http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=Om&last=10) for it that reads:

> **omnipreneur** (noun) : a new breed of entrepreneur who run his businesses anywhere where the action is or where the action is less, depending on the goal at hand.
>
> > Armed with high-powered laptops, top-of-the-line PDAs (personal digital assistant) cum-cellphones, and unlimited wifi access in any hotspot, omnipreneurs hit the road every day with a mission in mind—to outsmart the competition! —Nilo N. Poso, www.eenterprise.net, 16 May 2007

Comment: I want to find out what a "cum-cellphone" is, but I'm afraid of what Google will start showing to me in AdSense ads if I search for it.

Comment: @kotekzot have a look at the [definition of cum](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cum) and note the actual phrase is PDA-cum-cellphone.